# Can't boot to HD after installing 18.04 through a persistent usb

Tags: boot, 18.04, mkusb

I made a persistent usb with mkusb, but intentionally used it to install Ubuntu on my HD (e.g. not being interested in the persistent option this time). But upon booting I am not able to proceed without the usb. Even BIOS is unavailable on my samsung ultrabook, so I cannot run ordinary live USBs.

Current structure:

`sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 465,8G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0  22,4G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   5,6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sdb2   8:18   0  16,8G  0 part /
sdc      8:32   1    30G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   1  13,9G  0 part /media/juju/usbdata
├─sdc2   8:34   1     1M  0 part 
├─sdc3   8:35   1   244M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdc4   8:36   1     2G  0 part /media/juju/Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS amd64
└─sdc5   8:37   1  13,9G  0 part /media/juju/casper-rw`

Any tips?

Comment: It seems that you have installed vital parts of the bootloader in the USB pendrive. The steps to fix it may depend on the boot mode, so please let us know if you are booting in UEFI mode or BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode). When running, test with `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios`

Comment: Next time you can try to avoid those problems according to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Installing_-_using_the_Install_icon_on_the_desktop)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it describes the problem exactly. I also install boot in a different disk than /home. Never had a problem with that, except now with the persistent usb. Running the command gives `efi` as output.

Comment: If you have just installed Ubuntu (and not spent much time tweaking or saving files), it might be easiest to simple make a new installation. Otherwise you may need to modify some things, the location of the EFI system partition (copy it to the internal drive), maybe also modifying which partitions to mount or swapon. It may be fast but may also be tricky and time-consuming.

Comment: Thanks, I see that you have the EFI system partition on the pendrive (share it with the persistent live system).

Comment: I suggest that you do not touch the head end of the root partition **`/`**, but create a small partition for EFI booting 'behind' the root partition or somewhere in the other drive (steal some drive space for it from `/home`). The you can try to simply copy the content with `sudo -Hav source/ target` where source and target are the mountpoints of the current and the new EFI system partitions. Please notice the trailing slash in `source/`.

Comment: If you do not want to re-install and the simple copying that I suggested in the previous comment won't work, we need help from a real expert ... So good luck and let us know what you do and how you succeed.